# Cant apply CSS to Backbone View

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js, backbone-views

Only just started learning Backbone so this is probably me completely misunderstanding a core concept.

The code below is from my View object and there's a few things I don't understand...

1. Why the CSS change in highlightHero function isn't working. If I do a

   ```
   console.log(this.$el.children(".playerIcon"))
   ```

   afterwards I can see in the outerHTML property that the appropriate style has been added to the object but it hasn't made the change to the element in the DOM.
2. Why if I insert a deliberate syntax error at the bottom of highlightHero the whole thing works perfectly, albeit throwing an exception aswell.

.

```
initialize: function(){
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('change:isHero', this.highlightHero, this);       
},

events: {
    'click .playerIcon': 'toggleHero'
},

toggleHero: function(){
    this.model.toggleHero();//This just toggles a boolean
},

highlightHero: function(){
    if(this.model.get('isHero')==true)
    {
        this.$el.children(".playerIcon").css("background-image", "url('/imgs/user-red.png')");
        console.log(this.$el.children(".playerIcon"))
    }
    else
    {
        this.$el.children(".playerIcon").css("background-image", "url('/imgs/user.png')");
    }
},
```

Any explanation greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling this AFTER render?

Comment: The initial render is called from another View, render should also be called every time the model changes from the initialize function. If I call this.render at the bottom of highlightHero it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`highlightHero` is being called successfully after the `change:isHero` event and applying the CSS class which is reflected in the DOM. However, then the `change` event is fired, causing the View to re-render without the CSS applied, and it's too quick to notice. If you add a syntax error, the `change` event won't be called since the application crashed.

To resolve this, I suggest calling `highlightHero` in your render function and deleting the `change:isHero` event.